# Scrolling pictures increase (android)

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, imageview

Sorry for my english. Help figure out how to do this: There is a list of something, such as news and the top of the list there is a picture that if I swipe it down will increase and load a new piece of news. Prompt how to make itself an increase in the swipe down, I can not think of anything. The pictures about what I need(image [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nPMc.png), image [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvROf.png)) sorry links, i need 10 reputation

Answer (score 0):

[PullZoomView](https://github.com/Frank-Zhu/PullZoomView)

Is it what you want?